# How can I stream a ScriptMethod JSON response without the 'd' object?

Tags: asp.net, asmx, scriptservice

I have a pretty basic `ScriptMethod`:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void GetData(string token)
{
    Context.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
    Context.Response.Clear();
    Context.Response.BufferOutput = true;

    List<string> data = new List<string>() { "foo", "bar", "foobar" };

    using (var stream = new StreamWriter(Context.Response.OutputStream))
    {
        JsonSerializer.Create().Serialize(stream, data);
    }

    Context.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
}
```

If I hit this API via a GET, I receive an acceptable response:

```
["foo","bar","foobar"]
```

If I hit this API via a POST, instead, I receive a malformed response:

```
["foo","bar","foobar"]{"d":null}
```

How can I make this function write the response, without appending the `d` object?

Answer (score 1):

You don't don't have to handle the serialization yourself, let the framework do that for you.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<string> GetData(string token)
{
    return new List<string>() { "foo", "bar", "foobar" };
}
```

I think what you'll get back is `d[ [ "foo", "bar", "foobar" ] ]` but at least it's valid. The `d[]` construct is a security thing.

Comment: In the actual case, I'm using JSON.net to make complex transformations to the actual C# objects being sent in the response. This makes returning objects unfeasible, unless there's a way to have ASP.NET serialize with JSON.net and various custom resolvers/serializers.

Comment: maybe serialize everything to a `string` and return that, rather than writing directly to the stream. it'll still be wrapped in `d[]` but won't be mangled.

Comment: That's currently what I'm doing, but it's not ideal.

Comment: to do any better than that you'll probably have to roll your own request handler.